# Why does this pricing field li stack on mobile?

Tags: css

I think I am going insane. I cannot figure out why this pricing field all of a sudden stacks below 641 px. Can anyone help me out?
I think I need a new set of eyes to look at the code!

http://forfattarskola.staging.wpengine.com/bildkort/bestall-bildkort/

Good
[image]

Bad
[image]

Comment: It would help if you'd post your code here so we're not referencing a link.

Comment: If I knew what relevant piece of code to post I would. But on the other hand, if I knew where the changes were coming from I would probably not have asked the question to start with... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the code to look at and just the page source it looks like you need to change this css class to use inline-block and not block

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 641px) .gform_wrapper .ginput_container span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why the changes kicks in at 641 px. Nothing in my stylesheets are referencing that break point. But who knows. I gave up and simply added the inline-block definition and it works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: I see your site was made on wordpress, and with some themes and plugins... an advice.... don't try to understand... haha just fix.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#gform_fields_4 li {
    min-width: 200px;
}
#gform_fields_4 li * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

i tested this on your page through chrome debug, and seems to work. add this CSS to page and voilá!

Comment: i'll explain the problem: some style was setting the parent div to be smaller, and making the children elements, such as some spans, and inputs to be display:block... thus, breaking lines. with min-width so it doesn't get small, and the * selector for all children be inline-block